# Record not save after post call of edit through ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, edit

i want to post ajax call for edit record.When i click on update button it get all field against Employee_id but record not update in database.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int Employee_id) //this view will show records in popup
{

    List<Employee_And_Department> empdept = new List<Employee_And_Department>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connnString);
    var query = ("select Employee.Employee_id,Employee.Name,Employee.Contact,Department.Department_id,Department.Department_Name,Department.Salary,Department.Employee_id from Employee inner join Department on Employee.Employee_id = Department.Employee_id where Employee.Employee_id =" + Employee_id);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Employee_And_Department objEmployeeAndDepartment = new Employee_And_Department();
        objEmployeeAndDepartment.Employee_id = Employee_id;
        objEmployeeAndDepartment.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
        objEmployeeAndDepartment.Contact = rdr["Contact"].ToString();

        objEmployeeAndDepartment.Department_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Department_id"]);
        objEmployeeAndDepartment.Department_Name = rdr["Department_Name"].ToString();
        objEmployeeAndDepartment.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Salary"]);
        empdept.Add(objEmployeeAndDepartment);
    }

    return PartialView("Partial1", empdept[0]);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee_And_Department objEmployeeDepartment)
{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connnString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var query = ("update Employee set Name=@Name,Contact=@Contact where Employee_id=@Employee_id");
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_id", objEmployeeDepartment.Employee_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", objEmployeeDepartment.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", objEmployeeDepartment.Contact);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        var query1 = ("update Department set Department_Name=@Department_Name,Salary=@Salary where Employee_id=@Employee_id");
        using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query1,conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_id", objEmployeeDepartment.Employee_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department_id", objEmployeeDepartment.Department_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department_Name", objEmployeeDepartment.Department_Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", objEmployeeDepartment.Salary);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ListofEmployees");
}
```

Partial View Script for PostCall

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            $("#loaderDiv").show();
            var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Test/Edit",
                data: myformdata,
                success: function () {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                    window.location.href = "/Test/ListofEmployees";    
                }    
            })
        })    
    })

</script>
```

Comment: add your cshtml code to question too

Comment: Why is @Department_id a parameter? It's not being used in the Update. Is it required for the Update?

Comment: its required for get id of Department according to my thinking

Comment: @DaudRaza You add it as a parameter, but it's not being used in the SQL statement (query1).